# pseudo-Anosov suface automorphisms and algebraic intersection numbers

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I am looking for a reference about the relation between pseudo-Anosov theory and algebraic intersection numbers.

Let $S$ be an oriented surface and $\psi : S \stackrel{\sim}{\to} S$ be a pseudo-Anosov surface automorphism. For simple closed curves $\alpha, \beta \subset S$, it is known that the geometric intersection number $i(\alpha, \psi^n(\beta))$ grows exponentially as $n$ increases. And the exponential growth rate is the stretching factor of $\psi$.

I am wondering the following:

Let $\hat{i}(\alpha, \psi^n(\beta))$ be the algebraic intersection number of $\alpha$ and $\psi^n(\beta)$. Then, does   $\hat{i}(\alpha,\psi^n(\beta))$ grow exponentially as $n$ increases? If then, is the growth rate the stretching factor of $\psi$?

I am trying to find some references, but I could not find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

In fact, if $S$ is a closed surface of genus $\ge 2$ then there exists a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism $\psi : S \to S$ such that the induced action $\psi : H_1(S,\mathbb Z) \to H_1(S,\mathbb Z)$ is the identity, hence $\hat i(\alpha,\psi^n(\beta)) = \hat i(\alpha,\beta)$ is a constant independent of $n$.

The construction of such $\psi$ is easy. Start with an essential simple closed curve $c$ that separates $S$. Let $d$ be another simple closed curve that separates $S$ such that $d$ is transverse to $c$ and each component of $S - (c \cup d)$ is a polygon with $\ge 4$ sides. Let $\tau_c,\tau_d$ be the Dehn twists around $c$ and $d$, and note that each of them induces the identity on $H_1(S,\mathbb Z)$, and so $\psi = \tau_c \tau_d^{-1}$ also induces the identity. And by a result of Penner, the mapping class of $\psi$ is pseudo-Anosov.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.

I have a follow up question. In your example, the induced linear map $\psi_* : H_1(S, \mathbb{Z}) \to H_1(S, \mathbb{Z})$ is the identity. 
Generally, for a pseudo-Anosov $\psi : S \to S$, is there any relation between eigenvalues of the induced map $\psi_* : H_1(S, \mathbb{Z}) \to H_1(S,\mathbb{Z})$ and the stretching factor $\lambda$ of $\psi$?

Comment: The reason why I am asking the question is the following : 
In your example, $\psi$ is not geometrically trivial (for example, $i(\alpha, \psi^n(\beta))$ grows increasing exponentially), but some algebraic topological tools cannot detect this. 
I am wondering whether those algebraic topological tools cannot detect anything or sometimes detect something. And I guess that if they detect something, then that thing might be related to the stretching factor. 

Thanks again. I could not expect that an expert like you answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: A good thing to do with a followup question is to ask it as a new question, that way many people will see it besides me and you.

Comment: Yes you are right. First, I will try to answer the question by my self, and if I fail, I will post a new question. Thanks!